# htaccess convert to frendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**ORIGINAL URL:** `http://localhost/store/?til=product&id_product=25&title=blue-basket`

**WANTED URL:** `http://localhost/store/products/blue-basket`

I was wondering if there is some way to hide the variable of `id_product=25` if not, it should be something like this:

`http://localhost/store/products-25/blue-basket`

I have this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /store/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)?product&id_product=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /store/products=%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^products=(.*)$ ?til=product&id_product=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**RESULT:** `http://localhost/store/products=25&title=blue-basket`

Comment: You can add product id to the queryString, for example firefox hides the queryString...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /store/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /store/(?:index\.php|)\?til=product&id_product=([0-9]+)&title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /store/products-%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^products-([0-9]+)/(.*)$ ?til=product&id_product=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it's breaking all CSS/IMAGES/JS `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost....`

Comment: @Ered probably because all your CSS/images/JS are all relative URL links, so you need to make them all absolute URLs or add a relative URI base to the page header (something like `<base href="/store/"/>`